# How can I change the OPC-Slide (one page checkout js)

Tags: onepage-checkout

how can I change the slider effect at the onepage checkout?

I only want to fade in/out or simple "reload" every step of the checkout process.
I'm not a Pro in javascript. It's at /mytheme/js/opcheckout.js?!

THanks for your help.

Comment: Did you manage to add your sliding function?

Answer (score 3):

The functionality for opening steps is actually located in the file `[root]/js/varien/accordion.js` and only called from the `opcheckout.js` at each step. You can modify the function located on line 44.

Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13382961/387136) on SO on overwriting default javascript functionality. It would come down to something like adding the following to your own Javascript file

```
Accordion.prototype.openSection = function(section) {
        [...]
        your custom slider script
        [...]
    }
};
```

But since I'm no Javascript expert myself this will probably need a LOT of tweaking :)